# How do I simplify this complex resistor circuit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

[image]I have this circuit diagram and I need to find the current through the circuit.But I have no idea how to simplify this circuit.

I have tried applying Kirchoff's Current Law but could not do it.

[image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Look closely. What does the top 3$\Omega$ resistor do? Solve that first, then redraw the circuit without it.

Comment: @CuriousOne Can you provide a little more details,please?

Comment: I can, but that's all the help you need. The reason why they are giving you this circuit and not a really hard one is so that you learn to develop strategies to solve the simple ones without much effort.

Comment: As a side note, unless you need an analytic solution,  use of a Newton-Raphson backsolver  (TK!Solver,  or the R-package BB are two example) to iterate to an answer are a good way to solve circuits will tons of nodes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I took the liberty of redrawing this circuit for clarity. Can you take it from here?

[image]